# How to synchronize Play framework 2 with MongoDB and the steps to be followed

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, playframework, casbah

I have been working on this since days now but have not came up with any solution.
My target is to create a dummy project which uses Play framework 2 and mongodb as backend with scala used for UI only and the rest would be done in java.
Keeping in mind that similar questions were asked earlier but I personally didn't received any answer for my query.
Below are few links i checked out but didn't helped me..
http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/tutorial.html
https://github.com/mongodb/casbah
I'm a newbie so kindly correct me if i am wrong in any sense.
Thanks in Advance! :)
NOTE: I AM WORKING ON WINDOWS..

Answer (score 0):

Hm, actually there is ready to use solution,

Check [example application available at github](https://github.com/Mironor/Play-2.0-Java-MongoDb-Jackson-exemple)

It uses [MongoDB module for Play 2](https://github.com/vznet/play-mongo-jackson-mapper)

Works...